# See if file exists and rename using Windows command line

Tags: windows, shell, if-statement, command-line, cmd

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and am quite frustrated.

All I want to do is see if a file exists (which it does) and then rename it.  I am working in the command line in Windows 10.

```
IF exist C:\content\info.txt (
    ren "C:\content\info.txt" "C:\content\info_new.txt"
) ELSE (
    echo "Couldn't find file."
)
```

I keep getting the error "Syntax of the command is incorrect".  I know the file exists because I ran the following earlier.

```
if exist C:\content\info.txt echo "info.txt is in C:\content\info.txt."
```

I am entering all of this directly into the command prompt, and not calling it from a .bat file.  Am I missing something here?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

you don't have to give the full location while renaming the file. Just do this:

```
 IF exist C:\content\info.txt (
  ren "C:\content\info.txt" "info_new.txt"
 ) ELSE (
 echo "Couldn't find file."
)
```

Comment: no problem bro :) dont forget to give it a green check mark if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the directory first, then change the filename. Like this:

```
IF exist C:\content\info.txt (
      cd C:\content
      ren info.txt info_new.txt
 ) ELSE (
      echo "Couldn't find file."
 )
```

Comment: you don't know how to put `code` in StackOverflow Kevin?

Comment: I actually do, @Subaz.

Comment: There is absolutely no "need to go to the directory first, then change the filename" and as there is no indication of the existing current directory your `CD` command should read `CD /D C:\content`.

Comment: @Subaz, please see the [Be Nice Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).  Better to propose an edit than to be snarky to the poster.

Comment: @harry, I suggested the edit for the same and he rejected my edit and did that edit by himself lmao. what's that?

Comment: @Subaz I don't mean to offend you, but your edit suggestion did not really improve my initial post as it only removes the "line breaks" on the code tag. That's why I rejected it.

Comment: exactly. if it wasnt so useful then why would you reject my suggestion do the same exact edit by yourself?

Answer (score -3):

Here is working one liner, if the file is there, no need of else

```
IF exist C:\content\info.txt ren C:\content\info.txt info_new.txt
```